# Выбор значения по умолчанию и добавления класса

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать чтобы по умолчанию при загрузке выбирался Earth2 и проставлялся класс selected для icon2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flash .fleft a").click(function(){
        $("#flash .fleft a").removeClass("selected")
        $(this).addClass("selected")
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon1')) sendJS("Earth1")
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon2')) sendJS("Earth2")
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon3')) sendJS("Earth3")
    })
```

Comment: <pre>
$(document).ready(function(){
    //всё, что здесь выполняется, будет выполнятся при загрузке
})
</pre>
или я неправильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Не правильно поняли. Мне  нужно к выше написанному добавить, чтобы по умолчанию выбирался sendJS("Earth2") и для icon2 добавлялся selected

Comment: Замечание по коду - кешируйте jQuery-переменные внутри функции. Сама библиотека этим не занимается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flash .fleft a").click(function(){
        $("#flash .fleft a").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon1')) sendJS("Earth1");
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon2')) sendJS("Earth2");
        if ($(this).hasClass('icon3')) sendJS("Earth3");
    });
    $("#flash .fleft a.icon2").click(); //Иммитируем клик по icon2 после загрузки
});
```

Comment: не заработало, все равно по умолчанию грузиться 1земля